# To make all the links color gray

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the code so it makes all my links gray, but my current code only make the last link gray. I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body {background: #8B6914;
}
h1 {
background: #ffe7ba; color: #8B6914; font: bold 300%;
sans=serif;
align="center";}
div {color: #ffffff; font: bold 125%;}
p {color: #ffffff; font: bold 125%;}
ul,li{ color: #ffffff; font: bold 125%;}
td {width:40%;}
a:link { color: gray;}
a:visited {color: black;}
a:active {color: black;}
a:hover { color: red;}
img {
width: 30%;
}
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 8em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- my page -->
<h1> Welcome to My Homepage
</h1>
<div>
 Insert an image on this line, us e div tag <img src="wolf.jpg" alt="my picture" /> keep font         white and centered.
</div>
<hr />
<ul>
<li>Create a list with the font color gray and text size the same as you have been using </li>
<li>Make the last link to http://www.cnn.com</li>

<li><a href="index.html">Book index page</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Book contact page</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">Book about page</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN.COM </a></ li>
</ul>
<br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `a:visited` to gray as well?

Comment: You have some invalid CSS syntax there (like `align="center"`)...you should clean it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely because your `:visited` pseudo element is affecting all the visited links. I'm assuming you haven't visited the last link, thus, it appears gray while the other links (visited) appear black.